# Using If in JQuery

Tags: jquery, conditional-statements, if-statement

I'm using the jQuery Clean Calendar Plugin, and it's working well. However, in my jQuery code, I want to check whether any '/' is present in `textbox.val()`. Then I want to do some operations. How do I check if the value contains '/' in it?

Comment: I can't tell you how much this question depresses me.

Comment: Annakata, that's not very constructive, is it? He's clearly just getting familiar with jQuery, and likely programming as a whole. I mean no disrespect, but lets encourage those who are new to the field. We were once where they are too.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
   if (textbox.val().indexOf( "/") >= 0)
   {
   }
```

Same I guess will work for attribute:

```
   if ($( "#id").attr( "some_attr").indexOf( "/") >= 0)
   {
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to suggest a slightly more concise way to do it, using ternary and [match()](http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_match) instead:

```
$( "#id").attr( "some_attr").match('/') ? alert('got a forward slash') : alert('no forward slash');
```

Comment: I love the ternary operator, but I'm thinking it may confuse the original poster. He seems relatively new to programming, and the if/then structure might make more sense than the () ? : ; structure.

Comment: @Jonathan - I totally agree with you. I just felt like suggesting it as no-one else had, and to introduce a bit of variety.